# How to find out how many workers are being used by my Dask dataframe?

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I can use Dask no problems on a single machine

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
a = dd.read_parquet("c:/data/p03.parquet", columns="var0")
aa=a.value_counts().compute()
```

But how do I find out how many workers (or processes) is it using? I tried

```py
from dask.distributed import Client
Client()
```

and it shows

> Client: scheduler='tcp://127.0.0.1:56688' processes=4 cores=12

Does it mean that it's using 4 processes for my dataframe operation?

Answer (score 1):

This means that it has 4 processes, each with 3 threads available for your operation. Depending on your computation you may want to tune this towards more threads & fewer processes (generally better for things that release the interpreter lock, e.g. numeric work), or more processes & fewer threads (generally better for things that require the interpreter lock, e.g. string processing).

To get insight on how your operations were actually computed, see the diagnostics documentation, particularly on the dashboard: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/diagnostics-distributed.html#dashboard.